# UIScrollView question... loading images

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have a UIScrollView that does not do paging.  I am loading about 500 small (64x64-iPhone 192x192-iPad) images.  I do not want to load them all into memory.  I would like to load them as the user scrolls.

Can anyone tell me where I can set the images to display?  I have an object for each image that holds the image resource name, index number and x and y coordinate where it should be displayed in the UIScrollView.  I was hoping there was a method I could override where I could create a UIImageView and then add the view to the scroll view on the fly... maybe preloading 6 to 10 images at a time. Every sample I see uses paging and only displays one image at a time.

Any help or example is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

**EDIT:**

In the ScrollViewSuite examples from Apple there is a Tiling example.  That example has a scrollview that popups up displays images to select from. That is exactly what I am trying to do, but Ineed to load them on the fly. The sample loads all of the thumbnail images into memory.  Someone somewhere must be doing this because the iPod/iPhone and iPad do not have alot of memory to load all the images.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a UITableView for this?

Edit: [Might be worth looking at](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Scrolling/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Nope, my images are horizontal so UITableView does not work.  That would be perfect though.

Comment: Oh, it wasn't clear you wanted to scroll horizontally. You may want to add that to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has some really good demo code that shows how to do this. Check out [TiledScrollView.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/3_Tiling_Classes_TiledScrollView_m.html) especially the layoutSubviews method.

Comment: No, this sample does not do what I need.  The method you point out is for the tiled images.  I have what is shown in the thumbnail scroller.  I have approx. 500 images that I need to scroll.  Exactly like the sample, but the sample loads all the images into memory.  I want to load them on the fly.

Comment: It's fairly trivial to modify the sample code so that each tile is a different image and load them on the fly. The main point of the sample code is to show how to manage the reuse of the sub-views so you can scroll really fast. Sorry you didn't find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

write the code in following method of scrollview:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

I did the same. Load atleast few images in the beginning and then load those images in above method.

PROPERLY ALLOC AND RELEASE IMAGEVIEWS SINCE THEY CAN LEAD TO MEMORY LEAKS

Hope this works for you :)
Cheers :)

Comment: Yes, I think that may work, I have been fooling with that method.

Comment: It will work. I have used it to load 1040 images. If it works you should accept the answer :)

Comment: Dimple, thank you for the comment.  I believe it would work, do you have an example of what you did, or do you know of one?

Answer (score 0):

u can try making ur tableview horizontal by using CAAffinneTransform and giving the angle as (3.14/2) ie 90 degree annd can have a horizontal tableview with horizontal scroll and can use the above refrence given by MIKE A
regards...